# Please recommend Wi-Fi adapter (PCIe, USB) for wi-fi sniffer

Tags: wifi

Looking for a Wi-Fi adapter to set up a sniffer (Linux & Wireshark on a PC/laptop).
Support of .11ax or newer is not required, .11ac is enough.

Preferred something easily available.

P.S. I need to debug anomalies in connectivity between a station (embedded device) and AP (variety of COTS routers) such as reason of disconnect, possible violations of protocol...

Answer (score 1):

based on your wording, I don't know what else to say other than type in *wifi adapter* in amazon, or newegg, or some other retailer and buy whatever is cheapest and has acceptable reviews.

Make sure it says *supports windows* or *supports linux* or *supports whatever else* you are interested in.

you're not asking for anything specific or complicated, and 802.11ac is pretty much the norm today.

**update:** fwiw my experience with RHEL/CentOS 9 on older consumer (home use) motherboard (p6x58d-e) having realtek network (wired) was problematic, the linux install did not recognize that era of realtek chipset upon install.  I was told that the driver is available at ELREPO repository and would require a manual install.  So that being said, **maybe** not go with realtek, but it could've just been that older version of realtek wired network where as any newer or current realtek hardware would be fine.  But again whatever you buy make sure it says *supports linux* and also the **version** of linux you plan to use.

Comment: Well I expected recommendation at least of certain chipset. But thank you anyway.

Comment: stick with the name brands like TPLink, Netgear, Asus, and so on.  As to what *chipset* they use I don't know that detail, the major players are Qualcomm, Broadcom, Intel to name a few.  Is any one better than the other, couldn't tell you.  They all seem to work.  Probably best to identify what {chinese} chipsets to stay away from, which i couldn't tell you... would be those really inexpensive ones sold on amazon/ebay of a no name brand.

Comment: https://deviwiki.com/wiki/Wireless_adapters/Chipset_table